# Does a ball rolling up an inclined plane keep on spinning even after reaching its maximum height?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

Let's say initially a ball is purely rolling and then it starts climbing a smooth (no friction) inclined plane. At its maximum height, its translational kinetic energy becomes zero but the rolling kinetic energy remains constant (zero torque about COM), so does this imply it will keep spinning even though its linear velocity is zero at max height?

Comment: Yes, why wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, to change the rotational velocity requires a tangential force on the ball.  Since the ball is round, the contact force will always be pointed toward the center of the ball, thus no tangential force.

Comment: Yes, sure. W/o some torque to decelerate rotation it just keeps spinning.

Comment: Thank you for helping out, it felt very counterintuitive at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inclined plane is smooth so there is no friction thus no torque. And because there is no torque angular momentum will not change. So answer is yes it will keep spinning.